# «Как исправить ошибку «SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument » в коде python kivy»

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Это простой проект на python kivy (Калькулятор)

```
class CalculatorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical', padding =8)
        gl = GridLayout(cols = 4,spacing =3, size_hint = (1, .6) )

        self.lbl = Label(text = '0', font_size =40, halign = 'right', valign = 'center' ,size_hint = (1, .4), text_size (400 - 50, 500 * .4 -50))
        bl.add_widget(self.lbl)
```

Результат в консоли:

```
c:\prog>python main.py
  File "main.py", line 17
    self.lbl = Label(text = '0', font_size =40, halign = 'right', valign = 'center' , text_size (400 - 50, 500 * .4 -50), size_hint = (1, .4))
                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Comment: А между  `text_size` и `(400 - 50, 500 * .4 -50)` не должно быть знака `=` ?

Comment: Спасибо, просто ночью делал, голова не соображала.